# Rails - strip_tags - Not catching DOCTYPE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize, strip-tags

Given an HTML email, I'm using the following to strip down to just the text:

```
  body = body.gsub(/\\r\\n?/, "\n");
  body = body.gsub(/\\n\\n?/, "\n");
  body = simple_format(body)
  body = strip_tags(body)
```

But I'm now seeing that one tag gets passed this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
```

Which outputs like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe I should be using Hpricot

Comment: Rather than add comments to your own question, amend the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Hpricot to text, worked great

Answer (score 1):

I guess for strip_tags, which looks like it's been deprecated, considers the doctype statement neither a tag, nor a comment. You could strip it out separately:

string.gsub(/<!.*?$/,'')

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) for your parsing needs. It's very well supported, plenty fast, very flexible, and the basis of a lot of other HTML/XML type gems. It has a Hpricot mode, though I'm not sure why anyone would need that as its syntax is more full-featured.

In particular, to strip tags from HTML, I'd recommend looking into [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah). It can whitelist tags, and has several layers of cleansing it can do.